# javascript - sort nested json object

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, object, nested

I want to sort the following json object in javascript by the `"orderby"` key (see second json object for the output I require):

```
{
  "1": {
    "category": "Year",
    "value": "2028",
    "title": "Current Year",
    "description": "",
    "orderby": "3"
  },
  "2": {
    "category": "Year",
    "value": "2038",
    "title": "First Year",
    "description": "",
    "orderby": "4"
  },
  "3": {
    "category": "Year",
    "value": "2016",
    "title": "Base Year",
    "description": "",
    "orderby": "1"
  },
  "4": {
    "category": "Year",
    "value": "2018",
    "title": "Previous Year",
    "description": "",
    "orderby": "2"
  }
}
```

Output required:

```
{
  "3": {
    "category": "Year",
    "value": "2016",
    "title": "Base Year",
    "description": "",
    "orderby": "1"
  },
  "4": {
    "category": "Year",
    "value": "2018",
    "title": "Previous Year",
    "description": "",
    "orderby": "2"
  },
  "1": {
    "category": "Year",
    "value": "2028",
    "title": "Current Year",
    "description": "",
    "orderby": "3"
  },
  "2": {
    "category": "Year",
    "value": "2038",
    "title": "First Year",
    "description": "",
    "orderby": "4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not possible unless you're prepared to manually create that JSON output. Historically JavaScript properties did not have a defined order. The order has since been defined, but the logic is complex and there are a lot of edge cases. One of those edge cases is that numeric keys are sorted numerically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting object property by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort this array by using javascript `sort` function.

```
const data = {
  "1": {
    "category": "Year",
    "value": "2028",
    "title": "Current Year",
    "description": "",
    "orderby": "3"
  },
  "2": {
    "category": "Year",
    "value": "2038",
    "title": "First Year",
    "description": "",
    "orderby": "4"
  },
  "3": {
    "category": "Year",
    "value": "2016",
    "title": "Base Year",
    "description": "",
    "orderby": "1"
  },
  "4": {
    "category": "Year",
    "value": "2018",
    "title": "Previous Year",
    "description": "",
    "orderby": "2"
  }
}
Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => data[a].orderby - data[b].orderby).map(f => data[f])
```

Comment: @Genspec updated the code, replacing value keys with orderby.

Comment: Required output is an object, not an array.

Comment: Also, to get the output you're producing, might as well just do `Object.values(data).sort((a, b) => a.orderby - b.orderby);` No need for the additional key lookups and `map()` operation.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes Object.values is a better approach and yes my bad its returning array instead of object with custom keys.